# Pass additional parameter through event_generate?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Is there any way to pass a custom parameter (string for instance) through the event_generate() method?

The problem is that i have two threads. one of them should pass a variable which is required by event handler in the other one. I've tried to declare eventHandler with additional parameter e.g. def refreshCanvas(self, event, param) but then I am unable to pass param through event_generate().

I've also tried to pass it as an existing parameter 'state', which supposed to be a string, but it does not work either.

Class that generates an event:

```
class GameThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, gameInstance, gui):
        Thread.__init__(self)

        self.__gameInstance = gameInstance
        gui.event_generate("<<refresh>>", when="tail", state=str(self.__gameInstance.getState()))
```

The class which suppose to catch this event:

```
class App(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        parent.bind("<<refresh>>", self.refreshCanvas)

    def refreshCanvas(self, event):
        #something
        pass
```

Comment: related: [how to use Tcl/Tk bind function on Tkinter's widgets in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41912004/4279)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the data option as http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/event.htm#M16 says

> -data string
>       String may be any value; it specifies the user_data field for the event. Only valid for virtual events. Corresponds to the %d substitution for virtual events in binding scripts.

However I've found that it's not yet in Python (see: http://bugs.python.org/issue3405) for now I would suggest use something like a queue and pass the data to the queue and then generate the event and pull the data from the queue in your handler method

EDIT:

A side note I would be careful about using any threading with Tkinter in general. I would suggest looking into using mtTkinter to be on the safe side. mtTkinter is a wrapper around Tkinter that makes it thread safe.