# how to use Tcl/Tk bind function on Tkinter's widgets in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl, bind, tk-toolkit

Although Tkinter's derived from Tcl/Tk but it's not as complete as Tcl/Tk. Tcl/Tk bind function has some attributes which tkinter doesn't (e.g. %d that returns The detail field from the event https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/bind.htm#M24).
Tcl/Tk scripts can be used by "eval" function in python but i don't know how to declare a tkinter widget in Tcl/Tk script.

so how can i use this function and its attributes on Tkinter widget?

Comment: When you say "how can i use this function", what do you mean by "this function"? Are you referring to `eval`? Are you asking how to use `%d` in a binding?

Comment: I do mean "how to use %d in a binding"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are asking how to create a binding that makes use of the "data" field (ie: `%d` substitution), you will have to call some tcl code to make that happen. This requires two steps: create a tcl command that calls a python function, and use tcl to bind an event to that function.

First, let's create a python program that can create an event and set the "data" field (this assumes the existence of a global variable named `root`, which we'll create later). When this function is called, it will generate a custom event with the data field populated by a string.

```
def create_custom_event():
    root.event_generate("<<Custom>>", data="Hello, world")
```

Next, lets create a program to call that function on a button press

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(root, text="click me", command=create_custom_event)
button.pack(side="top", padx=20, pady=20)
root.mainloop()
```

Next we need to create a function that is called when the event is generated. We plan to set the `data` field, so this function must accept one value which is the value of the `%d` substitution.

```
def callback(detail):
    print("detail: %s" % detail)
```

Because you want to use the `%d` substitution we'll have to create the binding via Tcl. However, tcl doesn't automatically know about our python functions so we have to register the function with tcl. Then it's just a matter of calling `bind` via the tcl interface to set up the binding.

The first step, then, is to register the callback. We've already created the function, we just have to create a tcl function that calls this function. Fortunately, tkinter gives us a way to do that with the `register` command. You use it like this:

```
cmd = root.register(callback)
```

This takes a python function (`callback` in this case), and creates a tcl command which will call that function. `register` returns the name of that tcl command which we store in a variable named `cmd` (the name is irrelevant)

Next, we need to set up a binding via Tcl to call this command. If we were doing this in an actual tcl script, the command would look something like this (where "." represents the root window):

```
bind . <<Custom>> {callback %d}
```

The python equivalent is this:

```
root.tk.call("bind", root, "<<Custom>>", cmd + " %d")
```

Notice that there is a 1:1 correspondence between an argument to `call` and a tcl argument. Conveniently, the default string representation of a tkinter widget is the internal tcl name, so we can directly use the widget in the call (though, pedantically, perhaps we should use `str(root)`).

Putting it all together gives us this, which prints out "detail: Hello, world" when you click the button:

```
import tkinter as tk

def callback(detail):
    print("detail: %s" % detail)

def create_custom_event():
    root.event_generate("<<Custom>>", data="Hello, world")

root = tk.Tk()

button = tk.Button(root, text="click me", command=create_custom_event)
button.pack(side="top", padx=20, pady=20)

cmd = root.register(callback)
root.tk.call("bind", root, "<<Custom>>", cmd + " %d")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: here's [how it is used to show the output of an external process in a tkinter GUI](https://gist.github.com/zed/42324397516310c86288#file-kill-process-py-L31)

Comment: @BryanOakley It turned out to be a race condition. I'll delete my comments now.