# How to get the Label widget from tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

frame = tk.Tk()
lbl = tk.Label(frame, text=line)
lbl.bind("<Button>", lambda x=lbl, y=frame: delete_and_create(x, y))
```

this is the function:

```
def delete_and_create(wid, frame):
    wid.pack_forget()
    lbl = tk.Text(frame)
    lbl.pack()
```

When I try to do `wid.pack_forget()` I get an exception:

```
AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'pack_forget'
```

When I try to print `wid` this is what I get:

```
<ButtonPress event num=1 x=50 y=10>
```

Meaning, instead of transferring the Label widget (`lbl`) I'm transferring the event `bind` to the function `delete_and_create`

Is there a command for the Label widget in which I can get the widget?

Comment: every function that is triggered by a binding parses the *event-object*. Please do a quick research on tkinter and bind.

Comment: Change `lambda x=lbl, y=frame: delete_and_create(x, y)` to `lambda _, x=lbl, y=frame: delete_and_create(x, y)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to use Tcl/Tk bind function on Tkinter's widgets in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41912004/how-to-use-tcl-tk-bind-function-on-tkinters-widgets-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Atlas435 said, `tkinter` passes an event object when it calls the function. Your lambda doesn't take that into account. That is why you need to change it to `lambda event, x=lbl, y=frame: delete_and_create(x, y)`